# Run Borland turbo c++ 10 IDE project from command line

Tags: c++, command-line, jenkins, c++builder, borland-c++

I'm trying to integrate a legacy borland turbo c++ project into jenkins task and I need to be able to compile the project from command line.

Is there any way to get the compiler CLI information from the project so that I could make a batch file that compiles it?

SO: Windows 7

Comment: I've added something else you can try for later versions of c++ builder.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the commands being invoked by C++ Builder by exporting a makefile for the project.

1. Under menu goto *Project*->*Export a Makefile*.
2. Once exported open a cmd.exe shell to the generated makefile's location.
3. Run the makefile with borland's `make.exe` tool:

   > **make** -B -K -n -f"*projectMakefileGoesHere*"

   - `-B` will traverse all the dependencies ignoring age.
   - `-K` will keep any temp response files used during the build.
   - `-n` do a dry-run printing the commands that would've been called in an actual build.

The link commands will be in the `MAKE0xxx.@@@` response file where "*x*" is a number assigned by make.

For later versions of C++ Builder, the `.cbproj` project is actually a msbuild project file. You can use msbuild to print the build commands used for the project. eg.

> **msbuild** "*project.cbproj*" -p:Configuration=Debug -clp:ShowCommandLine -v:n

Unfortunately, msbuild doesn't have a dry-run option so it'll end up building the project. Another idea is to create a simple logging program that replaces `bcc32.exe` compiler and `ilink32.exe` linker. With this, you can see exactly what options and switches are being passed to the tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply greatwolf, but I can't find the option to export a Makefile. I fix the title, the IDE we have is c++Builder 10 (2005) not 6. Any hint?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no c++ builder 10. Are you sure you're not mistaking it for something else? Do you mean C++ Builder 2010?

Comment: Well, the entry in start menu says it's "Borland developer studio 2006", but the about window in the IDE says "Borland® C++Builder® for Microsoft® Windows™ Version 10.0.2288.42451 Update 2 Copyright © 2005". I'm reading in some external tools to convert bds2makefile, but all of that seems to be non-free tools. I'm considering to try your suggestion on making a logging program.

Comment: In that case it's (C++ Builder) 2006.  Call it by the published name :)  (Do you refer to XP as Windows 5.1?)

Comment: Funny thing is that the folder containing the exe is called BS4 as borland studio 4. Anyways, I'm managing to do somewhat I want by invoking the IDE with command line flags. That way I can automate the builds. It's not the answer to the question I ask, but it was the best I could find. Here's an example: bds.exe "project.bdsproj" -b -o"CompilerOutput.txt"

Comment: @Rombus If you're still working on this, you can take a look at Darko's custom free [*bds2mak*](http://cablemodem.fibertel.com.ar/mega/bds2mak.0.8.zip) and see if it can work for you. Apparently the bdsproj2mak that comes with borland dev studio 2006 has a lot of [***reported problems***](http://borland.public.cppbuilder.commandlinetools.narkive.com/wDH94Pf8/bdsproj2mak-any-word-on-fixes) that's gone unfixed.

Comment: Thanks @greatwolf ! On monday I will try it out. I couldn't find a download link for that bds2mak